# Dynamically generated buttons in React do not re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have two buttons, a tweet button and a facebook like button. On each page I'd like these to show.

On the first load, the buttons load just fine. However when I move to the next page, the buttons are no longer loaded. Additionally, if I go back the buttons are no longer there.

I've tracked this down to the fact `react-router` doesn't re-render the DOM when the new page loads. Since these buttons are generated with some javascript it won't fire again. The javascript replaces a temporary div with a (sometimes large) element representing the button.

Currently I packed the javascript into `componentDidMount` so that it fires correctly for each button component. This works fine until the second page, as discussed above. Additionally, I have tried placing the code again in `componentWillReceiveProps` and it doesn't change anything.

How can I get this code to run again so I can have my social buttons on each page?

EDIT:

Here is an example component that I am using:

```
class TwitterButton extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.twitterMessage = encodeURIComponent("test tweet");
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    // Code from twitter's website for loading the button in
  }

  render() {
    const twitterUrl = `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?${this.twitterMessage}`;

    return <a className="twitter-share-button" href={twitterUrl} />;

  }
}
```

The code in  `componentDidMount` fires just fine in the first page, however the second page it does not.

Comment: 1) Please show the code.
2) you are not using any pattern like redux, right?

Comment: @Nitesh I really can't link my entire app here to demonstrate it won't reload. I'll put up a small template of one component to demonstrate it. Yes I am using `react-redux` and `react-router`.

Comment: I am not sure how you are rendering your first and second page. But 'componentDidMount' is called only once when first time any component is rendered.

Comment: @Nitesh they are being rendered via a `ConnectedRouter` component using `react-router`.

Comment: 1) have your tried react-async-script-loader to inject the twitter script? it might be a problem with the js initialization from twitter 2) putting code in componentDidMount and this.twitterMessage in componentWillMount will only fire once mounted, the problem is that your component won't mount again on your second page. You should pass the message via props instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a well known issue, described in [`react-router` docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/dealing-with-update-blocking):

> You may run into issues with components not updating after a location change despite not calling shouldComponentUpdate yourself. This is most likely because shouldComponentUpdate is being called by third-party code, such as react-redux's connect and mobx-react's observer.
>
> With third-party code, you likely cannot even control the implementation of shouldComponentUpdate. Instead, you will have to structure your code to make location changes obvious to those methods.

That happens because `react-redux` will not re-render connected component if its props did not change. And your `componentWillReceiveProps` will not be called at all. What you have to do is to:

1. Pass current location to connected components, which should be re-rendered on location change.
2. Add your `window.twttr.widgets.load()` to both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`, so that twitter button initializer do its work both after initial mounting and after each re-rendering.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you give a brief example of (1) for me?